# How to change the order of 3 of 4 divs randomly on page refresh

Tags: jquery

I have the code below

```
<div class="allContent">
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div id="headline"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>

<script>
    $(".allContent").html($(".allContent .content").sort(function(){
        return Math.random()-0.5;
    }));
</script>
```

I've gotten to randomly change the order of the content, but the `#headline` disappears. I want to keep the `#headline` in the same position and achieve the same effect. Can someone please help with my code?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than replacing all the elements using `.html()`, you could append/prepend the elements.

Given the code you provided, this should work:

```
$(".allContent").append($(".allContent .content").sort(function () {
    return Math.random() - 0.5;
}));
```

In doing so, the headline will always be the first element (because the other elements are appended).

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/4cmwbdxt/)

```js
$(".allContent").append($(".allContent .content").sort(function () {
    return Math.random() - 0.5;
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="allContent">
    <div class="content">a</div>
    <div id="headline">b</div>
    <div class="content">c</div>
    <div class="content">d</div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could also just include *all* the children in the random placement:

```
$(".allContent").append($(".allContent").children().sort(function () {
    return Math.random() - 0.5;
}));
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/uf0u9bpu/)

..after reading your question again, it appears that you want the headline to remain in the same place. You could use the following:

```
$('#headline').insertAfter($('.allContent .content').eq(0));
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/te8jdLff/)

Comment: I want to keep the `#headline` in the same location, so after whatever the first <div> is every refresh. Is this possibe? @josh crozier

Comment: @二宮耕太郎 Did you see the last example?

Comment: sorry, when I refreshed it the first time, it moved. THANK YOU!

Comment: @二宮耕太郎 If the position of the headline changes, you could also use this - http://jsfiddle.net/eb73krvj/